# Can't add a background image with umbraco inline

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I'm trying to add a image from my media picker to my website. It needs to be placede as a inline in my header as a background image. But it won't get on my webpage.

Header code:

```
<header style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-image: url('@Umbraco.TypedMedia(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("backgroundimage"))')"></header>
```

And yes the Alias is: backgroundimage

How can i make it visual on the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Umbraco.TypedMedia(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("backgroundimage"))` will return an `IPublishedContent` object.  You need to render out it's `Url` property in your in-line code.

Try this:

```
@{
    var backgroundImage = Umbraco.TypedMedia(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("backgroundimage"))
}
<header style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-image: url('@backgroundImage.Url')">
</header>
```

If you want to validate whether you have a valid image or not (i.e. the user has specified one) you could take it a step further and do this:

```
<header 
 style="width: 100%; height: 100%; @(backgroundImage == null ? null : "background-image: url('" + backgroundImage.Url + "')"
>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried every referenced way i can find, and the ONLY thing that worked for me was to put the whole url string plus its quotes into a string variable, and then put that variable in the background-image declaration alone. Anything else stripped my url encoding.

```
string BkgImage = '"' + mediaItem.Url + '"';
 <a href="@post.Url" class="post-news__thumb-bkg" style="background-image: url(@BkgImage)">
  <img class="post-news__spacer" src="~/Images/spacer.gif" alt="@alt" />
 </a>
```